# Why datetime.weekday(datetime_obj) gives different result than datetime_obj.today().weekday()?

Tags: python, datetime

Why datetime.weekday(datetime_obj) gives different result than datetime_obj.today().weekday()??

Ex:

```
 y = datetime.strptime('1/1/2016 00:09:55','%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
 print(y.today().weekday())  # output: 3 ('Thursday')
 print(datetime.weekday(y))  # output: 4 ('Friday')
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say that `y.today()` calls the `datetime.today()` method, but it's not related to the value of `y`, whereas `weekday(y)` returns the weekday of `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y.today()` actually returns a new `datetime` object with the current date, unrelataed to the `datetime` object `y` currently stores.

The above code is equivalent to

```
y = datetime.strptime('1/1/2016 00:09:55','%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(datetime.today().weekday()) 
print(datetime.weekday(y))  # or just y.weekday()
```

Which understandably will not *always* output the same.